# No "status" in error hook

Tags: ember.js

According to [this page](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/), you can have an "error" action in the actions hash in the application route which looks something like this:

```
actions: {
  error: function(error, transition) {

    if (error && error.status === 400) {
      // error substate and parent routes do not handle this error
      return this.transitionTo('modelNotFound');
    }

    // Return true to bubble this event to any parent route.
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, when the server returns a 403 (or presumably any other error status) the "error" argument does not have a "status" property.  The only way I can get the status is like this:

```
actions: {
  error: function(error, transition) {
    var status = error.errors[0].status;

    if(status == '403') {
      return this.transitionTo('index');
    }

    // substate implementation when returning `true`
    return true;
  }
}
```

Not a big deal, but it seems wrong to do error.errors[0].status.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: can you specify your ember version. Seems to work fine here http://ember-twiddle.com/186bb291a2b738c96d2f?numColumns=1

Comment: @AcidBurn If server responds with error string and status, it works as described in question. In your demo, however, server responds with 403 status and without any error message.

Comment: Inside your error action, pause the execution with chrome debugger and check the call stack in the right side. As far as i could analyze, ember just forwards the error object from the rsvp. It doesn't process it anywhere. so i am guessing this has nothing to do with ember. Maybe it was their mistake assuming all the error objects will be in the same format and mentioning it so in the documentation.

Comment: Also ember just gave an example code of how to use the action and that you will be getting an error object. They never stressed on the format of the error object.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, ember tries to pass errors in some 'general' format, suitable for all cases. And in some cases backend may respond with more than one error. I think that's the reason why we have an array of errors in error action.

Comment: According to the documentation, "status" should be a property on the "error" object.  The status is independent from whatever json the server returns.

Comment: You are free to submit an issue and tell ember devs how wrong they are